# Find whether object is a member of array by few key/values pairs

Tags: javascript

I have a following problem. I cant figure out how to find whether objects is a member of array by few keys.

```
target_obj = {‘a’:1,  ‘b’:2, ‘c’:3,  etc….}

array_of_objects = [
{‘a’:7,  ‘b’:9, ‘c’:3,  etc….},
{‘a’:2,  ‘b’:6, ‘c’:0,  etc….},
{‘a’:1,  ‘b’:2, ‘c’:6,  etc….},
{‘a’:0,  ‘b’:9, ‘c’:2,  etc….},
{‘a’:1,  ‘b’:2, ‘c’:3,  etc….},  // === target_obj , exclude from comparasion
]
```

`target_obj` is always a member of `array_of_objects`.

Goal is to find whether `array_of_objects` contains at least one objects that has `‘a’` and `‘b’` values same as target_obj   but exclude target_obj  from this comparison as well ( otherwise it is always true).

In this example `{‘a’:0,  ‘b’:9, ‘c’:2,  etc….}` would be the  matched objects and this should give us ‘true’ as a result.

Thank you

Comment: You could iterate the array and for each item, iterate the target_obj keys and compare them

Comment: the main trouble her is to filter out target_obj  from iterator

Comment: If you are using lodash you can use the `isEqual` function to filter out target_obj from the array. If you don't use lodash you can pick only the minimal functionality that you want from the library

Comment: Is your target_obj always inside the array ?

Comment: yes, iside array. No lodash is used unfortunatelly